# Ignore file with git without defining it in .gitignore

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a jenkins pipeline which checks out a git project which has it's .gitignore file.
This is the content of my workspace:

```
file1.txt
src/
.gitignore
```

Now the jenkins pipeline will load a script in the workspace:

```
file1.txt
src/
.gitignore
script.sh
```

This behaviour will happen for a lot of projects. We are not able to put the `script.sh` in the `.gitignore` of each project. (I know it's possible but see this as a temporary solution):

Is there some `git` command which we can execute inside our pipeline which will tell git:
ignore the script.sh (+ ignore the other stuff which is in `.gitignore`).

Our script will perform `git commits` and we want to avoid to have the script in the repo too, without editing the `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the following script before you do the commit;

```
echo script.sh >> .git/info/exclude
```

**.git/info/exclude** acts just like .gitignore, but it will only affect the local repository - changes to this file cannot be commited.

Comment: I see the file after a local checkout but not in Jenkins after the checkout?

Comment: You'll need to run the script as part of the Jenkins build

Comment: It works when I create my own .git/info path. Any idea why I have to create this by myself in my jenkins workspace? It's by default there when I just clone it locally.

Comment: Anything inside the .git folder on your workspace is not included in a commit, which is why you have to get Jenkins to create it after doing a clone.

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially do a sparse-checkout. It's used to locally define what content you wish to include in this working environment, meaning it will never affect the remote.

You'd have to execute the following from a shell script (or the like) after the file exists:

```
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo "!script.sh" > .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo "/*" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout`
```

The second line excludes script.sh from git activity while "/*" includes the rest of the files.

Note that single ">" means overwrite file contents, which may not be what you want. Use double if you wish to append.

Documentation for sparse checkouts are at the bottom of [this page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree)